# CSS relative should ignore all childs, relative to parent

Tags: html, css

i like make some positioning without float. is there any way to get position: relative; to be relative to parent, ignoring all other child. can not use absolute because the parent is not.

```
.myDiv
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.myDiv1
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relativ;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myDiv2
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relativ;
    top: -20px;
    left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myDiv3
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relativ;
    top: -50px;
    left: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Not like excepted: http://jsfiddle.net/VLk6m/16/ (all children are on the same top position)

Comment: would you please make your question clearer? and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Note that you have a typo in there. `position: relativ;` instead of `position: relative;`.

Comment: Having an image of what you *do* want would also help.

Comment: @gamehelp16 My question is clear. Can not see this useless comment anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's not `relativ` it's `relative`.
2. You can use `position: absolute` if their parent has `position: relative`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IorgaMihai/VLk6m/17/)

Comment: typo alert compounded by copy and paste!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/VLk6m/19/

This is certainly possible if you spell relative correctly.

You have `position: relativ;`  it should be `position: relative;`  Then just 0 out your `left` and `top` attributes.

```
.myDiv
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.myDiv1
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myDiv2
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myDiv3
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```